# Disposing POI temporary files in multithreaded system

Tags: java, excel, multithreading, apache-poi

I'm using POI SXSSFWorkbook for creating XLSX files in multithreaded system.
Since I read that there are issues with disposing the temporary files when using the `"DefaultTempFileCreationStrategy"` (with the poifiles directory), I created each thread its own temporary directory:

```
private TempFileCreationStrategy createTempFileCreationStrategy(File poiTempFileDirectory) {
    return new TempFileCreationStrategy() {
        @Override
        public File createTempFile(String prefix, String suffix) throws IOException {
            if (!poiTempFileDirectory.exists()) {
                poiTempFileDirectory.mkdir();
            }
            File newFile = File.createTempFile(prefix, suffix, poiTempFileDirectory);
            return newFile;
        }

        @Override
        public File createTempDirectory(String prefix) throws IOException {
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

This is the code which runs while finishing handling the SXSSFWorkbook object:

```
try {
    // Write the Stream and close it
    workBook.write(outputStream);
    outputStream.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    throw e;
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw e;
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;
} finally {
    // Close the workBook
    workBook.close();
    // deleting the temporary files
    workBook.dispose();
}
```

But even so, from time to time, I'm getting an exception during the dispose. One thread is throwing an exception while trying to delete the temporary files of another thread and the message is:

```
dc319a2c-a663-4cb7-9f13-f7e8cc14c186/poi-sxssf-sheet-xml6608967316211277648.gz (No such file or directory)
```

This happens while the ID in the directory name is the threadID of the other thread.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Thread Local so that you can get separate TempFileCreationStrategy object for each thread.

For further information refer [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html)

```
public class Main {
    private static final ThreadLocal<TempFileCreationStrategy> threadLocal =
         new ThreadLocal<TempFileCreationStrategy>() {
             @Override protected TempFileCreationStrategy initialValue() {
                File file = null;
                // to do create thread folder
                return createTempFileCreationStrategy( file );
         }
     };

     private TempFileCreationStrategy createTempFileCreationStrategy(File poiTempFileDirectory) {
        return new TempFileCreationStrategy() {
            @Override
            public File createTempFile(String prefix, String suffix) throws IOException {
                if (!poiTempFileDirectory.exists()) {
                    poiTempFileDirectory.mkdir();
                }
                File newFile = File.createTempFile(prefix, suffix, poiTempFileDirectory);
                return newFile;
            }

            @Override
            public File createTempDirectory(String prefix) throws IOException {
                return null;
            }
        };
    }

    public void process() {

        TempFileCreationStrategy tempFileStrategy = threadLocal.get();

        // to do excel file logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer, i'll try it (unfortunately this error happen rarely so it will be hard to follow it).